# How to get this json data by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I am currently working on a telegram bot, and I want to add a function that can search Wikipedia, and I want to know how to get the 'extract' part without knowing the pageid from this wiki API that I fetch from URL?

For example this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=wiki&utf8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Object.keys(data.query.pages).map(pageId => data.query.pages[pageId]).map(page=>page.extract)
```

where `data` is the json you got